# Regex for a redirect, what am I getting wrong?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a whole bunch of urls that end with some varation of this:

http://www.example.com/events2?type=day;start=2009-07-31%2000:00:00

We have hundreds of URLs with variations in the parameters that we want to redirect to a single URL

http://www.example.com/category/news-events/events/

This is the redirect we have set up which doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^events2.*$ /category/news-events/events/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

What are we getting wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: check @ http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ This condition was not met` The page is great to debug htaccess files, cause it will directly show you the rewriten/redirected/converted url.

Comment: This is a great tool. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this rule in root .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^events2/?$ /category/news-events/events/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Aha! So we were missing the .+ at the Query string. That fixed it.